# Exibir imagem após usuário logado com o CORDOVA

Tags: php, apache-cordova

estou desenvolvendo um app com o CORDOVA e o objetivo é mostrar a imagem do perfil do user quando logado via ajax, realizei alguns testes e cheguei até aqui:

```js
$("#email").html(localStorage.email);
var imageUser="https://source.unsplash.com/random/700x300"+md5(localStorage.email);
$("#profile").attr('src',imageUser);
```

Funciona depois de logado, só que não estou sabendo, inserir a imagem do banco na variável. Valeu pessoal.

Comment: Como armazenar e recuperar imagem para localStorage? https://stackoverflow.com/q/19017401/3658278

Comment: Beleza implementei no projeto deu certo, menos na inserção da imagem no banco. quero que fique no perfil do cliente toda vez que ele entrar (padrão)